# Javascript working before page rendering in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I try to convert a [HTML template (Bootstrap 5)](https://bootstrapmade.com/flexstart-bootstrap-startup-template/) to Gatsby template. CSS and pages working expected but in HTML template there is a **main.js** file and it need to load after page rendered.

I modify the **main.js** file like that;

```
import { Swiper } from "swiper/swiper-react.cjs.js";
import GLightbox from "glightbox/dist/js/glightbox.min.js";
import AOS from "aos";
AOS.init();

export const onClientEntry = () => {
  window.onload = () => {
    console.log("deneme");
    /*rest of code*/
  };
};
```

In here I try two way. One of them, I create **main.js** file inside **src->components->assets->js** folder. Then in layout.js I try to import that file.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Breadcrumb } from "gatsby-plugin-breadcrumb";
import Header from "./partials/header";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import useSiteMetadata from "./hooks/siteMetadata";

import "./assets/css/style.css";
import "./assets/js/main.js"
```

However in here in debug not hit the any method inside onClientEntry. So I decide to change my way.

Secondly, I try to add code inside **main.js** to **gatsby-browser.js**. That's time again getting `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` because of html is not ready yet.

My file structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`window` (and other global objects like `document`)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) are not available during the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) because this action is performed by the Node server (where for obvious reasons there's no `window`, yet) so you can't access directly to `onload` function. In addition, accessing these global objects outside the scope of React (without hooks) can potentially break [React's hydration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/) process.

That said, you have a few approaches:

- Using React hooks. Specifically, [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with empty dependencies (`[]`) fits your specifications, since the effect will be fired once the DOM tree is loaded (that's what empty deps means):

  ```
  const Layout = ({children}) => {

     useEffect(()=>{
       mainJs();
     }, [])

     return <main>{children}</main>
  }
  ```

  Assuming that your `./assets/js/main.js` file has a `mainJs()` function exported, this approach will load it when the DOM tree is loaded. For example:

  ```
  const mainJs= ()=> console.log("deneme");
  ```

  The `console.log()` will be triggered when the HTML tree is built by the browser. Tweak it to adapt it to your needs.
- Adding a `window`-availability condition like:

  ```
  export const onClientEntry = () => {
     if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
        window.onload = () => {
          console.log("deneme");
          /*rest of code*/
        };
      }
  };
  ```

  Alternatively, you can output the `console.log` directly in your `onClientEntry`, depending on your needs:

  ```
  export const onClientEntry = () => {
    console.log("deneme");
    /*rest of code*/
  };
  ```

You can even combine both approaches by adding a `useEffect` in your `gatsby-browser` if it works for you.